# PHP Array - Fetch all sub values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im trying to fetch all `[labels]` along with its `[id]` from the below array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [elements] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [label] => This is a Page 1 Question 1
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [label] => This is a Page 1 Question 2
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [elements] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [label] => This is a Page 2 Question 1
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 13
                            [label] => This is a Page 2 Question 2                          
                        )
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [elements] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [label] => This is a Page 3 Question 1                           
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 21
                            [label] => This is a Page 3 Question 2                           
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I did some research and tried using the below code, but it return something else.

```
foreach($elements as $key => $value) {
     echo $value['label'];
     echo $value['id'];
}
```

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such structure of array you should iterate **twice**:

```
foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['elements'] as $element) {
        echo $element['label'];
        echo $element['id'];
    }
}
```